# Select one (highest) score per userid OR nickname column

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I'd like to get the highest score for each user, however scores will either have a userid (INT) or nickname (VARCHAR) column filled in; the other will be null.

Ideally would get results like this:

```
nickname, userid, score
abc, NULL, 1500
NULL, 22, 1250
NULL, 15, 1100
xyz, NULL, 750
```

Comment: what is the actual data in the table?

Comment: also why doesn't each score have a userid? you should't be putting in a nickname as a unique column because more than one person can have that nickname...

Comment: Yes, nicknames are for people who aren't registered. So they can be duplicates. The data in the table would be as shown in the question, though there would be multiple entries per userid and/or nickname. Mureinik's answer works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT   nickname, userid, MAX(score)
FROM     my_table
GROUP BY nickname, userid
```

Comment: This has been automatically flagged as low quality, because there is no explanation what this code excerpt does.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work! Didn't realize it was that simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select COALESCE(nickname, userid) as userid_or_name, max(score) from yourtable
Group by COALESCE(nickname, userid)
```

Comment: This has been automatically flagged as low quality, because there is no explanation what this code excerpt does.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_id,user_name,MAX(score) FROM user_score
GROUP BY user_id,user_name
```

[see result](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a93dcc/1)

Comment: the data you put in is the expected results... so its not that

Comment: This has been automatically flagged as low quality, because there is no explanation what this code excerpt does.